# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.4.3:test

Tags: java, maven

Hi I want to install one program from my university which should work. 
 https://github.com/graphium-project/graphium

I tried to install through command prompt but it didn't work (see pic [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PcJHb.png).). I also tried in Eclipse and Update project (this advice I found on forum) but then it is same.

thank you for any help

Comment: Are you really using such an ancient version of surefire plugin? Based on the version you are using an 10 year old version? Please upgrade....

Answer (score 2):

As per the errors on the command prompt, it looks like test cases are failing. You can go to surefire-reports folder of the failing module and see what is actually failing. 
If the only thing you want is to install the project, then you can simply skip running tests using `mvn clean install -DskipTests`

Answer (score 0):

You can also run `mvn clean install -e` to see more logging of the error that caused the test to fail